# Stuck on divides relation proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck on even where to start for this, as I just started learning about the divides relation.

`Prove: For integers r, s, t, and u, if r|t and s|u, then rs|tu.`

Can anyone offer any tips about where to begin here?

Comment: First, start with the definition of what if means for one integer to divide another.

Comment: And apply it to translate the two hypothesis and the goal.

Comment: Got it -- I do understand that if r|t, then t = rc for some c...

Comment: @AnneBauval so I've got 

t = rc

u = sd

tu = sdrc

Am I on the right track there?

Comment: Perfect! so $tu=(\dots)rs$ with $(\dots)=?$ and you have won.

Comment: @AnneBauval, ah I can't figure out the next step. How do I move the dc out without changing the tu side?

Comment: You have the right idea but try to start from the end. What does it mean to say that $rs|tu$? Like the other two divisions, it means $tu=krs$ for some $k$. Can you use the other divisions to find $k$?

Comment: John's $k$ is my $(\dots).$ You can "move the $dc$" (inside $sdrc$) by [*commutativity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property#Mathematical_definitions) of the multiplication.

Comment: @AnneBauval Do you mean that I could really only get tu = rsdc due to commutativity?

Comment: @AnneBauval is it simple enough to just say dc = 1? Can I just declare that? Multiplicative identity...

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No, you have no control on $d,c.$ You only know "$t = rc$ for *some* $c$" (and similarly, "... for *some* $d$"). You are given $t,r$ and the fact that *there exists* a $c$ such that blabla. Such a $c$ is implicitely given, you cannot change it.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh wait, I'm doing a divides relation, so if tu = cdrs and cd = some k, then it is accurate to say that rs|tu where tu = rs*k

Comment: "and you have won"

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Gleaned through help in the comments:$$t = rc$$$$u = sd$$$$tu = cdrs$$$$cd = k$$ for some integer $k$$$tu = k*rs$$thus, $$rs|tu$$